# MySQL: Passing DateTime Columns in functions

Tags: mysql, sql

opLastTurn and TurnTime are DateTime Columns of mytable

```
SELECT ADDTIME(opLastTurn,TurnTime) AS result FROM mytable;
```

but it returns Null,what is wrong?

Comment: which data typesa  are opLastTurn and TurnTime  ?  show a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @ scaisEdge they're type is datetime

Comment: for both the columns ??

Comment: I think the 2nd argument must be a time data type. Or just the time value at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument must be a datetime expression. The second must be a time expression. If they can't be parsed that way, the function gives up and returns NULL.

**WRONG:** Both arguments are datetime.

```
mysql> select addtime('2017-08-17 11:00:00', '2017-08-17 11:00:00');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| addtime('2017-08-17 11:00:00', '2017-08-17 11:00:00') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

**RIGHT:** Second argument is time:

```
mysql> select addtime('2017-08-17 11:00:00', '11:00:00');
+--------------------------------------------+
| addtime('2017-08-17 11:00:00', '11:00:00') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 2017-08-17 22:00:00                        |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The second  arguments should be a time .. so try using

```
SELECT ADDTIME(opLastTurn, time(TurnTime) ) AS result FROM mytable;
```

Comment: dear scaisEdge i have tried it with a time column too but still returns null

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem ,i get this result because some of my data was like below

datetime:0000-00-00 00:00:00
time:03:00:00
or 
datetime:2017-00-02 05:00:00
time:00:00:00
each row which has a default value for these field cased the null  return

Thanks aloot @scaisEdge,Bill Karwin,Phil K